# Add numbers to tablewidget

Tags: python, qt

I have tablewidget named `tableSum`, it has 1 col and 5 rows, and 1D array of numbers(float) `Sum_main`.  How to print in table this array?

Tried this, but its not working:

```
for n in range(5):
            self.ui.table_Sum.setItem(n, 0, QTableWidget(Sum_main[row][0]))
```

Comment: presumably you meant either `n` or `row` but not both...  i have put this in the answer.

Comment: @D.L. oh, that was miss click, I edited it. I making cycle by 'n'.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looping through `n` then the iterable parameter should be `n` and not `row`... basically one or the other.

so change `row` to `n` (or `n` to `row`) if that is what you intended to do.

```py
for n in range(5):
            self.ui.table_Sum.setItem(n, 0, QTableWidget(Sum_main[n][0]))
```

Comment: oh, that was miss click, I edited it. I making cycle by 'n'. And still, it doesn't working, underlined QTableWidget word